# MailChimp TimeWarp scheduling - what date to pass and when to create campaign

Tags: php, mailchimp, mcapi

We have a cron job that runs once a day and sends daily emails through MailChimp. Now we would like to try sending them using TimeWarp feature, but I can't really understand how this should work.

I create a campaign with `'timewarp' => true` and schedule it with [campaignSchedule()](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/campaignschedule.func.php).:

```
$delivery = date("Y-m-d 10:00:00");
$chimp -> campaignSchedule($campaign, $delivery);
```

But when I open the campaign in MailChimp, there's different schedule date set in, although "TimeWarp" checkbox is checked.

What does this "needs to be schedule 24 hours in advance" mean? If script runs today, i need to schedule it for tomorrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you cannot have in `$delivery = date("Y-m-d 10:00:00");` today's date.
You should have `date('Y-m-d 10:00:00', strtotime ('+1 day'));` instead.

Please note that this can work only in case the script is being executed before 10 a.m.

I should rather have `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ('+1 day +1 hour'));`

Comment: Oh thanks now it shows correct status:scheduled in campaign list.